# How to get Azure Container Instance (ACI) exec command output using .net

Tags: azure, azure-container-instances

I'm using .Net SDK for ACI (Azure Container Instances) to run [an exec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/container-instances/containers/execute-command#terminalsize) command

In the response, I only get back [this object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.containerinstance.models.containerexecresponse?view=azure-dotnet) which doesn't tell me how to get the actual result of the command e.g. exit code and message.

My question is: how to retrieve the exec command results in .NET?

This is my .NET code:

```cs
string command = "ls";
var commandResponse = containerGroup.ExecuteCommand("container1", command, 100, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the [LogContent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.containerinstance.fluent.icontainergroup.getlogcontent?view=azure-dotnet) of the container in order to find out what happened. If you are interested only in the newest item, then you can pass 1 as `tailLineCount`. ContainerExecResponse has a `WebSocketUri` property as well, which may explain why you do not directly get the info you need in the response object. WebSockets are duplex channels of communication, differing from the request-response protocol-type and in the case of WebSockets, you establish a connection which may run for a very long time, occasionally responding. So here expecting an HTTP-like behavior seems to be a misunderstanding, at least if I look at the docs.