# How to execute a command in a running Azure Container Instance from Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-container-instances

I have tried to use the POST API mentioned in the official documentation. But every time I get status 200 even for wrong bash commands.

[image]

The output of Web Activity:

[image]
How can I get output of the *ls* command ?

Answer (score 0):

> How to execute a command in a running Azure Container Instance from Azure Data Factory?

I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and when I called this Rest API, **I received the default response of WebSocket Uri and Password.** This is because, A Rest API cannot decode a WebSocket response due to its complexity as per this [SO thread Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70887279/how-to-get-azure-container-instance-aci-exec-command-output-using-net) by Lajos Arpad. I tried replacing bin/bash with ls command and bin/sh but I still received the same default response as below: -

[image]

An alternative is to run a PowerShell script from [Custom Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-custom-activity) in Azure Data Factory.

PowerShell Command:-

```
Invoke-AzContainerInstanceCommand -ContainerGroupName test-cg -ContainerName test-container -ResourceGroupName test-rg -Command "ls"
```